# Time format of Pomodoro in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: time, libreoffice-calc, advanced-format

I'm using LibreOffice Calc in Windows 7 and I'd like to write a formula that, given a decimal number, converts it to hours and minutes. For instance I have this:
[image]

cell **E3** is `=($B$3*25/60)` i.e. it returns the amount of hours corresponding to **B3**, the number of completed pomodori (4, in this case). One 'pomodoro' is equivalent to a 25 minute indivisible block, hence the 25 in the formula.

In cell **F3** I've tried applying the `[hh]:mm` User-defined 'Cell Format' but I'm getting back '40:00' instead of 01:40, 1 hour and 40 minutes (0.67 * 60 ≈ 40 minutes). Can someone please help me? Is there a pre-configuered formula for this kind of calculation?

Comment: Try **=TIME(INT(B4*25/60), MOD(B4*25,60),0)** in **F4**, where **F4** is having hh:mm format, to get the desired results.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Will it also work if I want to use this number to later do subtractions/additions?

Comment: Yes, it is working at least in the cases I tried: I copied the formula from **F4** in **F5**. Then entered **5** in **B5** cell. Now enter **=F5-F4** in **F6**, **=F4+F5** in **F7**. You will now see **2:05** in **F5**, **:25** in **F6**, **4:10** in **F7** etc.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently **E3** is in hours but spreadsheet time format works on a days and fractions of days. Assuming that **F3** is equal to **E3** but with the format [HH]:MM, then **F3** should be divided by 24 to convert to days. Then the format returns 01:40.

Comment: your solution worked fine but can you please explain to me what was the problem in the first place? Why did I need to divide by 24 to get the correct form of `hh:mm`? What does it mean that the 'spreadsheet time format works on a days and fractions of days'?

Comment: A date in calc is an integer that is the number of days from the arbitrary start date (12/30/1899 for my calc), so today is 42066, which can be formatted as 03/03/2015 00:00:00. To add one hour to that you would add 1/24 of a day, or 0.0416667. So the date of 42066.04166667 will format to 03/03/15 01:00. Your number was 1.67 hours so dividing by 24 converted 1.67 hours to the days scale that the date time format requires.